# Start a tab fragments from an activity with the tabs layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabs

I have a tab fragments app. The problem is when I go into an activity inside my app and want going back to my tabs layout it returns without the tabs row layout. I can see only the specific fragment page without the row above (the tab's row) that makes me able to navigate between the tabs.
Do you know what can I do to solve it? How can I see the tab's row too?
Thanks for any help,

This is the first tab that I want to see back from the activity:

```
public class Tab1MyProfile extends Fragment  {

   @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_my_profile, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

This is the activity that contains code to go back to the fragment tab:

```
public class GameLive extends AppCompatActivity implements RecognitionListener {
    private Intent intent;
    private Button mStopButton;

    public void stopGame (View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to finish the game?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        Tab1MyProfile fragment = new Tab1MyProfile();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_live);
        mStopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEndGame);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopGame(view);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

And this is the activity that contains all the tab's fragment:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Tab1MyProfile tab1=new Tab1MyProfile();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Tab2StartGame tab2=new Tab2StartGame();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Tab3StatsArea tab3=new Tab3StatsArea();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Tab4Settings tab4=new Tab4Settings();
                    return tab4;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "My profile";
                case 1:
                    return "Start Game";
                case 2:
                    return "Stats Area";
                case 3:
                    return "Settings";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Thank again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you replace everything inside the `onClick` method of the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` with `GameLive.this.finish();`. This will close the GameLive activity on click and return you to the previous activity, which should be the one that contains the missing navigation bar.

Comment: That  a good idea, but there is an activity between the activity I want to close and the fragment which contains the missing navigation bar.. Do you have any idea how do I close two activities at once?

Comment: Are you sure you want to close both activities at once? This can lead to confusion if you think from the user's perspective. If you really want to manipulate the activity stack there are ways. For example, have a look at Intent flags.

Comment: Thank you for your helping! I decided to take your advice and close only one activity :)